# Reynolds number formula

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

Reynolds number $$(R_e) =\dfrac{\rho v d}{\eta}$$

Also
 $$(R_e) =\dfrac{\rho A v^2 }{\frac{\eta A v}{d}}$$

$$R_e=\dfrac{\text{inertial force}}{\text{force of viscosity}}$$

My question is how $$\rho A v^2=\text{inertial force} ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you are moving an object with cross-sectional area $A$ with speed $v$ through a fluid of density $\rho$. Every second you sweep out a volume $V = Av$, and the mass of the fluid contained in that volume is $m = \rho Av$.

To make the fluid move out of your way you have to accelerate it, which requires a force, and this force will turn out to be the inertial force. Let's suppose that you have to accelerate the fluid to match your own speed $v$, then the momentum change is $mv$ and using the equation for $m$ above the momentum change per second is:

$$ \Delta p = \rho A v^2 $$

But the rate of change of momentum is just the force, so our end result is that the inertial force due to the motion through the fluid is:

$$ F = \rho A v^2 $$

Comment: In last paragraph,do you mean rate of change of momentum in unit time (1 sec)?

Comment: @Ramanujan: yes, $\Delta p$ is the change in momentum in one second so it is the same as the rate of change of momentum.